# Angular momentum operators and representations of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, quantum-mechanics

Consider the following standard triple for $sl(2,\mathbb C)$,
$$H=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 
\end{matrix}\right) 
\qquad X=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{matrix}\right)
\qquad Y=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
Let $\rho:\mathfrak{su}(2)\rightarrow \text{End}(V)$ be a lie algebra homomorphism such that for any $A\in \mathfrak{su(2)}$ we have $\rho(A)^*=-\rho(A)$. We extend this to a complex linear map $\rho:\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb V)\rightarrow \text{End}_{\mathbb C}(V)$. 
Consider the angular momentum operators defined by $L_j=\frac 12 \rho(\sigma_j)$, where $\sigma_j$ are the pauli matrices.

I want to show the following

> Let $v$ be an eigenvector of both $L^2$ and $L_3$. Show that there is a unique linear space $W\subset V$ that is invariant under $\rho$, such that $v\in W$ and $\rho |_W$ is a finite dimensional irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$.

I think I need to show that the space of vectors which are eigenvectors of both $L^2$ and $L_3$ is finite. I believe this should be the set $L^n_+v$ and $L^m_-v$ for $0\leq n, m \leq k$ for some $k$. I am not sure how to show this $k$ must be finite. 
If we had this then this should give that $dim(W)=2k$ or perhaphs $dim(W)=2k+1$ which would determine an irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$.

Note here $L_+=L_1+iL_2$ and $L_-=L_1-iL_2$.

**update**: I have shown that if $v$ is an eigen vector for both $L^2$ and $L_3$ with eigen values $j$ and $m$ respectively, then $L_+ v$ is also eigenvector with eigen values $j$ and $m+1$ respectively.

I used this to show that $\|L_+v\|^2=j-m(m+1)\|v\|^2$. This shows that $L^k_+v=0$ for some $k$. We can do something similar for $L_-$.

Since $L_+=\rho(X)$, $L_-=\rho(Y)$ and $L_3=2\rho(H)$, it follows that $L_+,L_-,L_3$ is a also basis?. Therefore to show that a space $W$ is invariant it is enough to show it is invariant under $L_+,L_-,L_3$.

Comment: Is $L^2=L_2$? Is $V$ finite dimensional? Do you consider the Pauli matrices as elements of $\mathfrak{su}_2$, as physicists might do, i.e. do we secretly multiply them with $i$? I guess you don't, as probably $L_+ = \rho(X)$ (and by the way, besides that, the triple from the beginning never comes up in the question).

Comment: $L^2=L_1^2+L_2^2+L_3^2$, and no I do not multiple the pauli matrices by $i$

Comment: So the Pauli matrices are hermitian, $\mathfrak{su}_2$ are the (traceless) skew-hermitian matrices, and hence the Pauli matrices are *not* in $\mathfrak{su}_2$, right?

Comment: yes, but the are in $\mathfrak{su}_{\mathbb C} (2)$?